# Maximum/Minimum difference between 2 functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have the following functions:

$y_1 = x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x + 3$

$y_2 = x^2 - 3x - 4$

Find the value between $0.8$ and $1.9$ which give the maximum and minimum difference between $y_1$ and $y_2$.

I have no idea how to tackle this problem. At first glance I'd say derivatives might have something to do with this, but that's just a guess. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you know anything special about the derivative of a function at a maximum or minimum that might help you locate them?

Comment: And don't forget to check the boundaries.

Comment: @Callus Well, it's 0..

Comment: @Phaptitude:  Right.  What function are you trying to minimize/maximize?

Comment: @Callus Well, judging from the function and the interval probably $y_1 - y_2$?

Comment: @Phaptitude: Yeah.  Maybe $|y_1 - y_2|$, but that kind of obscures the point.  Are you still stuck, or do you see the way forward?

Comment: @Callus Yes, I understand it now, thanks a lot! You should post it as an answer, so I can accept it.